# 4K to 1080p scaled resolution in ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, scaling

I'm using a NV Geforce 1080 Ti. Because this card doesn't support 120 Hz in 4K, I was using 4K mode with 1920x1080x120 Hz scaled. Is there such an option in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hello. From you question <Is there such an option in Ubuntu?> Option of what? You are also missing the version of Ubuntu information in the question.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I want to set display resolution to 4K but I want it to be a scaled resolution from 1920x1080.. Because only 1920x1080x120 Hz 4x4x4 is supported on 1080 Ti